# What is the difference between IdentityDbContext and IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

On what basis should one decide to use `IdentityDbContext` versus `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` in an ASP.NET MVC5 application?

What benefits do we get by using `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` instead of the non-generic `IdentityDbContext`?

Comment: "On what basis we decide what we should use IdentityDbContext or IdentityDbContext in MVC5 application" did you intend to write IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> here? Same in next sentence also where you ask about benefits?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` will let you use your own `ApplicationUser` class as the `User` entity. I.e. you can have custom properties on your users. The `IdentityDbContext` class inherits from `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` which means you will have to use the `IdentityUser` class for your users.

If you want to have more properties on your user objects than the few properties that `IdentityUser` provide (UserName, PasswordHash and a few more) then you may want to choose `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`